# VLOOKUP based on two column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a table with User IDs in one column. These are entered multiple times to show the result for a particular topic.

```
ID          Topic       Pass/Fail
71086686    Science     P
71086686    Maths       P
71086686    Tech        P
71086686    ICT         F
71086687    Science     P
71086687    Maths       P
71086687    Tech        P
71086687    ICT         F
```

I am trying to find a way to return the Pass/Fail result for a particular ID and topic.

I am trying to use VLOOKUP to do this but cant work out how to use multiple columns as values to look up against.

essentially i am trying to acheive the below:

```
Vloookup([ID] and [Topic], A:C, 3, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recommend to concatenate criteria and searchranges when you could use `INDEX` & `MATCH` combo.

```
=INDEX(C2:C9,MATCH(1,(A2:A9=Criteria1)*(B2:B9=Criteria2),0))
```

And confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Implement another `INDEX` if you want to remove the array entering:

```
=INDEX(C2:C9,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A9=Criteria1)*(B2:B9=Criteria2),0),0))
```

Comment: for Option #2 *(+1)*

Answer (score 1):

You can add another column with a formula `A2&B2`, then use Vlookup to find that value.

Let's say you add it in the new column A.

Then your formula to find the value would look like this:

```
 Vloookup([ID] & [Topic], A:D, 4, FALSE)
```

I use this to quickly find values that I need without typing long formulas.