# Excel - Speed Up Index|Match Array Calculations

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula, formula

I'm having some serious performance issues with an excel workbook I created. I need to pull data from another worksheet in the book that has 7 columns of data and about 300 rows.

The amount of data should be no problem - I think the issue I'm having comes down to an index|match array that has multiple match conditions. I'm wondering if there's another approach I can take, because the workbook is becoming aggravating to work with.

Here's some made up data:
[image]

This data is aggregated in a separate program from a database, and I output it to an excel file.

Here's a sample of a made up segment of a report:

[image]

Where the formula for the rows "Active Accounts" and "Online Enabled Accounts" are:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$G,MATCH($K$2&M$1,$C:$C&$A:$A,0),MATCH($L2,$D$1:$G$1,0)),0)}
```

and the formula for the rows "Both", "Online", and "Paper" are as follows:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($G:$G,MATCH($K2&M$1&$L6,$C:$C&$A:$A&$F:$F,0)),0)}
```

I have about 5 other "segments" that reflect similar data by different in this format across 13 months. With only 300 data records this workbook is still painfully slow to even apply formatting, so I'm hoping there's a better approach than to just use these arrows with Index|Match.

Comment: For one, you should avoid using whole columns as a reference ;). Imagine, checking a few 300 rows or 1048576.....

Comment: Use helper columns to concatenate the Lookup values then match on that column.  Then it will not be an array formula.  If that is not desirable you can get a small bump in performance by limiting the lookup range to the data set and not full columns

Comment: And FWIW, concatenating criteria is hardly a good idea anytime. Instead `MATCH(1,(Criteria1)*Criteria2)....` etc, which you can even make a non-array entered formula (still array) with `MATCH(1,INDEX((Criteria1)*(Criteria2)*(Criteria3),),0)`

Comment: @JvdV I'm a little confused by your comment. I wasn't aware that there was a reverse Index|Match - you have Match|Index in a formula, where it begins with `1`. Could you briefly elaborate on the purpose of `1`?

Comment: The very brief answer would be that `MATCH` looks for the very first appearance of `1` in the array created by the criteria, for example: `(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)*(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)` evaluates to `(0,1,0)`, returning `2` with `MATCH`. :)

Comment: @JvdV I've never seen MATCH(INDEX()). I don't even know if I understand how that would work, since Match() returns a cell position, and not a cell value. I've tried looking up examples of MATCH(INDEX()) and have no luck. Do you have examples of how this is used effectively?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084414/excel-match-range-without-specific-cell/58084498#58084498) is an answer I recently gave applying this technique. Obivously when you recieve a `MATCH` apply it in another `INDEX` :). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038224/vlookup-based-on-two-column-values/57038374#57038374) is another answer where I recommended NOT to concatenate criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Select any range in your dataset and hit `CTRL + A` then hit `CTRL + T`. This will create a table you can reference as a named range.

Write the index match formula as you normally would except make sure to only select the data you're looking for this means **do not select the entire column, this is what's weighing down your system**, simply choose the ranges with the data you're looking at.

You'll notice as you highlight your data it will say something like `Table1[Accounts]` what this means is it's accessing that named column's datarange. This will allow your formula to scale as the table grows (or shrink as needed), and not calculate any farther than needed. This will save your computer a tremendous amount of computing power while it calculates.